# Kaa demo application on Amazon aws

Tags: kaa

I installed Kaa (0.10.0) in Amazon aws directly, and tried to run test the platform by running the demo applications given. I'm trying the "Data Collections Demos" but when i downloaded the binary for Java SDK and tried to run from local machine it gives me

> "java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out"

And log file shows that it's trying to connect - `ec2-52-201-214-219.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9889` whereas my Kaa instance ip is different `(ec2-13-.......)`.

And it does not give me the "changeKaaHost" option as it was available in (0.7.0) references youtube.

Any help or guide in changing the host or pointing me in right direction will be really helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Incredibly my custom Kaa application is trying to connect to the same IP (52.201.214.219), with the same error of course.
Could this be an issue with Kaa 0.10.0?

Comment: @Roses - Below script given by MrKoin does the required work, please use this script.                                                                                         echo "sudo sed -Ei 's/(gui_change_host_enabled=).*$/\1true/'" \
"/usr/lib/kaa-sandbox/conf/sandbox-server.properties;" \
"sudo service kaa-sandbox restart" | \
ssh -i <your-private-aws-instance-key.pem> ubuntu@<your-aws-instance-host>

Answer (score 0):

open this file with any text editor `/etc/kaa-node/conf/kaa-node.properties` scroll down to line where it says `transport_public_interface=YOUR_PUBLIC_INTERFACE` and then change YOUR_PUBLIC_INTERFACE to the real IP of your instance and then restart kaa service and generate new sdk

Comment: Hi Mohamed, I did this thing and it's working fine from desktop with Java SDK but not able to test the sample application from android using Android SDK.

Comment: try to generate a new sdk targeting android device and clean the project then rebuild again, if still didn't work I suggest sharing your code in a new question

Comment: Already posted code here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738355/basic-kaa-mobile-application-with-android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you made changes in your AWS instance but did not reflect them in your kaa sandbox config. You can try the following solution which I used myself:

Solved it by using following steps: 1. Changed the ipaddress in the admin panel> general settings to my ec2 host IP address with port as 8080

Using SSH, logged into ec2, changed the user to user:kaa, password:kaa, used: sudo /usr/lib/kaa-sandbox/bin/change_kaa_host.sh host_ip Downloaded the new SDK and created a new app. Data was received in the DB.

Comment: Hi Anil, I did this thing and it's working fine from desktop with Java SDK but not able to test the sample application from android using Android SDK.

Comment: If you look at the changes done above, all changes/configurations have been done on the kaa instance/server. As long as the device/linux is able to send data to the outside world, it would be able to connect with kaa if you are using the kaa sdk created after making the above changes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you mentioned has number of parts:

1. AWS usually assignes IP addresses to machines at the machine start time and frees on shutdown. This means that if you Kaa instance on AWS was stopped and then started again, you need to change the Kaa host settings on that instance, re-generate the SDK and re-build your application.
2. Kaa 0.10.0 Sandbox for AWS has an issue with Management page which is hidden. There is a [JIRA](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/KSF-116) issue for this.

You can use the below workaround to enable the Management page on Sandbox Web interface:

```
echo "sudo sed -Ei 's/(gui_change_host_enabled=).*$/\1true/'" \
"/usr/lib/kaa-sandbox/conf/sandbox-server.properties;" \
"sudo service kaa-sandbox restart" | \
ssh -i <your-private-aws-instance-key.pem> ubuntu@<your-aws-instance-host>
```

**Note**: this is a multi-line single command that works correctly in *bash* (should also work in *sh* and others, but that is not tested).

**Note 2**: don't forget to replace

```
<your-private-aws-instance-key.pem>
<your-aws-instance-host>
```

with the respective key name and host name/IP address.

Comment: Hi MrKoin, I did this thing and it's working fine from desktop with Java SDK but not able to test the sample application from android using Android SDK.