# Basic Kaa mobile application with android sdk

Tags: kaa

Trying to connect to Kaa Server with Android SDK :

1. Added downloaded android sdk jar as library in application.
2. Code
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private Context mContext;
   private KaaClient mClient;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mContext = getApplicationContext();

   ```
   mClient = Kaa.newClient(new AndroidKaaPlatformContext(mContext), new SimpleKaaClientStateListener(){
       @Override
       public void onStarted(){
           Toast.makeText(mContext, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       @Override
       public void onStartFailure(KaaException exception){
           Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   },true);

   mClient.start();
   ```

   }
   }

But not getting Success message.

Is there any tutorial out there to follow for Android SDK ?

Regards,
Hiten

Comment: Any errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate SDK right base on your application and choose Target Platform is Android.
And you can recheck way to add library in android studio.

Comment: Thanks Nguyên, i forgot to update. Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This query is solved now. It's working as expected.